# How to pass a file as parameter in mapreduce

Tags: java, caching, hadoop

I want to search for particular words in a file and display its count. When the word to be searched is a single word, I am able to do it by setting the configuration in the driver like below :

Driver class :

```
Configuration conf = new Configuration();
    conf.set("wordtosearch", "fun");
```

Mapper class :

```
public static class SearchMapper extends
        Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, IntWritable> {
    // Map code goes here.
    private final static IntWritable one = new IntWritable(1);
    private Text word = new Text();


    public void map (LongWritable Key, Text value,Context context )throws IOException,InterruptedException{


         Configuration conf = context.getConfiguration();
            //retrieve the wordToSearch variable
            String wordToSearch = conf.get("wordtosearch");
        String txt= value.toString();



        if(txt.compareTo(wordToSearch)==0){
            word = context.getCurrentValue();
            context.getCurrentKey();
            word.set(txt);
            context.write(word, one);

        }
```

But when there is a list of words in a file, I dont know how to pass it. Some posts refers to use distributed cache but while doing that I am getting "distributed cache is deprecated" error. Are there any similar methods in the new api to pass the file ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there is also a way in the new API.

First, store the file in HDFS. Then, in the Driver class (in the main method), do the following:

```
Configuration conf = getConf(); 
... 
Job job = Job.getInstance(conf); ...   
job.addCacheFile(new Path(filename).toUri());
```

Finally, in the mapper class (for instance in the `setup()` method), do the following:

```
URI[] localPaths = context.getCacheFiles();
```

If you have a single file, it should be stored in `localPaths[0]`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:judge the parameter wether is a file, then according to the type of parameter execute the operation respectively

Answer (score 0):

If the list of words has a reasonable size, you can still pass it to the configuration:

1. Driver class: read the file
2. Driver class: add the list of words in the configuration, doing for instance conf.set("wordListToSearch", "fun:foo:bar"
3. Mapper class: read the configuration and retrieve your list of words